# Cannot install packages either in command line or Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic, terminator

I was trying to install 'terminator' package specifically. I got this error :

```
E: Type '--2017-01-30' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type '--2017-01-30' is not known on line  1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

When I tried to do it by Synaptic Package Manager, I got almost the same error(attached) and system did not let me to open it.

Please help me to fix this. needless to say, I am new to Ubuntu :)
[image]

Comment: Edit your question to include the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list` has a wrong syntax.

But it seems useless to install terminator package. You could try this:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list.bak
sudo apt-get update
```

and try to install terminator again

Hope it helps

Comment: Tnx friend ! I just removed it and it is fixed now.